# Display block in span is not working. How can I make it span the same width as the previous span?

Tags: css, sass, ng-bootstrap

I am using [these bootstrap components](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/rating/examples) in angular to have some ratings and I get the following code:

```
<span class="ng-star-inserted" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <span _ngcontent-oof-c136="" class="star ng-star-inserted">
    <span _ngcontent-oof-c136="" class="half" style="width: 70%;">★</span>★
  </span>
</span>
```

The first two `span` are 20px wide, but the last one is 598px. I need the last one to be exactly as the previous ones in order to apply the corresponding width % and get the star covered until the appropriate percentage (see the "Custom decimal rating", where the fourth heart is only partially covered).

I've read everywhere this is done with a `display: block` but it doesn't work. I copied the styles from the example:

```
    .star {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 3rem;
      color: #d3d3d3;
    }
    .full {
      color: red;
    }
    .half {
      position: absolute;
      display: inline-block;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: red;
    }
```

These `span` are inside some other `div`, and some of them have `display: flex`. I deleted this flex but I still have the same problem.

How can I make this last `span` to be as wide as the parent one? Could it be some previous div is affecting? How?

Thanks

Comment: According to your HTML snippet, you are opening three spans and closing two. Is this correct? Maybe that's your problem

Comment: good catch but no, it was an error of copy-paste... :-(

Answer (score 0):

maybe try `.affectedspan {all:unset;}`

Comment: If I try `all:unset` the size is now correct, but the two stars (the grey and the red ones) do not overlap. If I set again only `position: absolute`, the stars overlap again but the size is again wrong. I'm getting crazy...